# how to change the innerHTML of a div ( using the DIV id ) at angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular

I got some programmatically-created divs such as below.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;">
   {{item}}
   <div id="badge{{i}}">this area will be updated at .ts</div>
</li>
```

So practically speaking, we end up with dom elements like this:
`badge0`, `badge1`, and so on.

And I need to update the innerHTML of these divs from the ts side, again programmatically.

Basically, the code should do something like: 
`find the div with the id badge6` and `update its innerHTML with "blah blah"`.

What's the syntax that would put me in touch with those divs?

Comment: If you had a way to obtain the div content from a method call like `getDivContent(i)`, would that satisfy your needs?

Comment: Yes, that'll do the job but what's missing in that custom function is how to target that DIV.

Comment: I feel like this is super simple, way simple problem to solve, but just cannot see the darn solution.

Comment: to the downvoter.. why the downvote? please do not tell me it is because you have not done any research on this matter stuff.

Comment: @AverageJoe if the content of div is dynamic than I believe you should store it inside a variable and than using interpolation binding you can show it on the screen. Updating DOM using a reference variable is not recommended in angular4

Answer (score 0):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;">
   {{item}}
   <div id="badge{{i}}">{{setItem(i)}}</div>
</li>
```

And add logic in .ts:

```
setItem(index) {
  if (index === 6) {
    return 'blah blah';
  }
  return 'whatever';
}
```

You shouldn't use `innerHTML`, that's not an angular way.

Comment: so in this case, you would not even need the div, would you? My goal is to increment / decrement a number that corresponds to the badge. That's why I named the div it as badge. Obviously, what I posted is not the actual code that I got. I just created a representative but extremely watered down version of it. Thru the process, I forgot the present the need for read and write capability. Anyway, If a certain condition match within the item, I want to increase the number, otherwise decrease it.

Comment: Sorry I went to sleep. Yeah, you don't need the div. The `{{}}` is for string interpolation. You can put any logic in it and the result will be displayed as a string. So in the `setItem` method you can have the condition that if some criteria is met you increase value and return it (that value will be then displayed). Or leave the value alone, or decrease it, it doesn't matter. It's a normal function, nothing special about it. For you is important that the result can be displayed in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) (useful if the content has some HTML tags, see  [this article](https://lishman.io/angular-2-interpolation)):

```
<div [innerHTML]="getDivContent(i)"></div>
```

or [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----):

```
<div>{{ getDivContent(i) }}</div>
```

With the public method in the component class:

```
public getDivContent(index: number): string {
   return some content...
}
```

Comment: ConnorsFan, I tried your pointers but failed at it. Then bite the bullet and developed a more complex solution and the challenge is now over. I basically turn the div to `<div>{{badgeCountForPanel[i]}}</div>` and then build a solution at the ts which keeps the badgeCountForPanel array correct all the time. That did the trick. Nw I'm trying to make this badgeCountForPanel multidimensional so I can have this: `badgeCountForPanel['panelGroup1'][i]` (this way, it's possible to have  one global var & multiple panelGroups on the same page. Challenge now stepped up but I know how to kill it. ThankYou

Comment: Yes, you can replace the method `getDivContent()` with an array item of the component class. By the way, you may consider removing "using the DIV id" from the question title.

Comment: just removed the DIV id. that was totally unnecessary and boxing the mind...  But I run into an issue initializing the badgeCountForPanel. When it is single dimension, no issues. This just works `badgeCountForPanel = [];`